# MongoDB stopped running with VirtualLock & Fatal Assertion error message

Tags: mongodb, fatal-error, teamcity-9.0

I was running some test using TeamCity and those test will use MongoDB. This test will take approximately 4 hours to finish. After 1-2 hours of running, all the remaining tests started failing. I checked on the server and find out that the MongoDB services has stopped running. Checked the log file and found the following;

> 2016-03-11T09:30:14.212+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49398 #272 (38 connections now open)
>   2016-03-11T09:30:54.104+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49400 #273 (39 connections now open)
>   2016-03-11T09:30:54.566+0100 F -        [conn273] Failed to VirtualLock: errno:1453 Insufficient quota to complete the requested service.
>   2016-03-11T09:30:54.566+0100 I -        [conn273] Fatal Assertion 28828
>   2016-03-11T09:30:54.567+0100 I -        [conn273]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure
>
> 2016-03-11T09:30:56.142+0100 I NETWORK  [conn216] end connection 127.0.0.1:49218 (38 connections now open)
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.443+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_windows.cpp(174)                                              mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.443+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(180)                                     mongo::`anonymous namespace'::printSignalAndBacktrace+0x74
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.443+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(236)                                     mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x76
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.443+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] MSVCR120.dll                                                                                              raise+0x1e9
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.444+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] MSVCR120.dll                                                                                              abort+0x18
>   2016-03-11T09:30:56.444+0100 I CONTROL  [conn273] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(172)                                                     mongo::fassertFailed+0xf0

Machine spec:
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (64bit)
CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2630
RAM : 16GB

MongoDB
version : 3.2.1 Enterprise
storage engine : Wired Tiger with encryption

I ran the same test and it executed successfully with the following Mongo versions:
-MongoDB 2.6.11 community edition
-MongoDB 3.0.9 community edition
-MongoDB 3.2.1 community edition
-MongoDB 3.2.1 Enterprise (Wired Tiger without encryption)

Anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: What is the test to replicate this?

Comment: it is a regression test for a component in a CMS platform

Comment: That doesn't inform us of anything. There is a reason why the server presents this message, and that reason is because of the code that you are running. Without the code, no-one can really give you a solution, which BTW is most likely a fault in the code being run. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36049895/edit) link on your question to include code that reproduces the problem. Otherwise this is off-topic and destined for closure.

Comment: yes sorry. i can't provide the code because its in a nuget package (contains around 1700 tests). The tests in the package are dependent on the CMS platform and there is a lot of confidential data that I can't share. Just wondering if anybody knows why does it fail only on MongoDB with encryption and not with any other setup. Is there any MongoDB settings that I can tweak to fix?